# 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' using Shopfiy Craft Plugin

Tags: plugins

I have set up the Craft Shopify plugin on a new build.

I have also created a 'Shopify Product' field in the CMS on my entry within my Products channel.

However, whenever I try to view the product in the back end I get this error:

[image: Shopify error]

[image: Shopify error 2]

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with 'https://' being in the store's URL in the CMS.